# commands executing in piping in UNIX

Tags: unix, pipe

when I write a command

```
$ echo date
```

then it prints "date" as it is i.e it doesn't run date program.
But when I write

```
$ echo date | wc
```

then correct answer is produced as if date was run. How piping is making difference here ?
Please explain.

Comment: Not to mention, I can't seem to repro this anyways... `echo date | wc` gives me 1-1-5 on a ubuntu system, which is the same result as `wc` and then typing `date^D`.

Comment: Check again, its not :)

Comment: echo `\`date\`` | wc would produce the results you are talking about. Or better, date | wc. `echo` prints whatever comes after it, unless $() or `` tells the shell you want the output of another process.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo date | wc
      1       1       5
```

as bytes counter == 5 (= sizeof("date"))
it seems that date wasn't run

but

```
$ echo date | xargs time
```

runs date as command

Comment: Ok..date wasn't running, instead it gives no. of characters of date.
But still, it should show 1 1 4, as date has 4 characters.
Why is it showing 5?

Comment: Because there is a line feed character after the string "date"

Comment: But there is no linefeed character after date. It is simply date|wc.
so only 'd', 'a', 't' and 'e' are passed to wc.

Comment: `echo` will add a line feed for you. Use `-n` to avoid the line feed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

Try:

```
echo date | cat > here.out
```

then try:

```
echo `date` | cat > here.out
```

Comment: Congrats for a "Useless Use of Cat Award" :-) http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: :)) Eh, guess I have to polish my answers.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla - he _was_ trying to demonstrate this while using a pipe similar to what the OP described. So in this case, its not a useless `cat`, since it does make a sensible demonstration, given the question. +1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 'echo' sends the following text to the standard output. The text, in this case, is 'date' so what you show won't work. This will: echo|date because date now produces the text for echo.

Answer (score 0):

echo `date` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how bash uses strings.

If you look at what get's stored in those variables

```
d1=date
d2="date"
d3='date'
d4=`date`
```

You will notice that d1,d2 and d3 just are strings that contains "date", 
d4 however has the result of the executed command date.

If we then take this a step further and see if we can find any difference between those strings.

```
d4=`date +%Y%m%d`
echo $d4
```

That would mean that we now have "20100418" stored in $d4.

```
d3='$d4'
echo $d3
```

Now in $d3 we have printed the string "$d4", those exact 3 characters...

```
d2="$d4"
echo $d2
```

Now here we do have "20100418" stored in $d2 since we printed $d4 and saved that output into the variable $d2.

```
d1=$d4
echo $d1
```

And then you have a copy the content of variable $d4 into variable $d1.

Hope this clarifies a little how those strings work.

And now back to your question.

```
cj@zap:~$ echo date | wc
      1       1       5
cj@zap:~$ echo `date` | wc
      1       6      31
cj@zap:~$ date | wc
      1       6      31
```

Now what does that actually mean? The man wc gives us this:

> NAME
>          wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

So "1       1       5" just told us that we have 1 newline, 1 word and 5 characters, 
and that matches date\n.

And "1       6      31" will match "sön 18 apr 2010 10.07.25 CEST\n", since that was what my date command gave me...